# TypesScript Generic syntax for Array containing another array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find the correct syntax for the interface where an array contains another array. The outer array contains the inner array.

I am not looking for logic in  the code

```
   export function deleteNestedArrayItem<U, T<U> >(
      outerArray: T[],
      outerIndex: number,
      innerIndex: number
    ) {
//code does here 
    }
```

Cannot wrap my head around the Syntax for the generic `<U, T<U> >`.

The associated data structures are

```
export class Item {
  constructor(public title: string, public description: string) {}
}

export class Skill {
  constructor(public id: string, public name: Item, public proficiency: number) {}
}

export class Category {
  constructor(public id: string, public name: string, public skills: Skill[]) {}
}
```

Instantiated here:

```
const skill1 = new Skill(uuid(), new Item('HTML', ''), 9);
const skill2 = new Skill(uuid(), new Item('TypeScript', ''), 5);
const skill3 = new Skill(uuid(), new Item('Unix', ''), 7);
const skill4 = new Skill(uuid(), new Item('Windows', ''), 9);
const skill5 = new Skill(uuid(), new Item('Illustrator', ''), 9);
const skill6 = new Skill(uuid(), new Item('Latex', ''), 9);

const cat1 = new Category(uuid(), 'Languages', [skill1, skill2]);
const cat2 = new Category(uuid(), 'Operating Systems', [skill3, skill4]);
const cat3 = new Category(uuid(), 'Miscellaneous', [skill5, skill6]);

const initialState: State = {
  categoryList: [cat1, cat2, cat3],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't get why do you need ids for arrays. Arrays are ordered data structures and should not contain custom properties like objects.

If array of objects with ids is suitable for your case, I'd go like this:

```
interface HasId {
  id: string
}

function deleteArrayItemById(arr: HasId[], id: string) {
    return arr.filter(item => item.id !== id);
}

let a: HasId = { id: '1' };
let b: HasId = { id: '2' };

const result = deleteArrayItemById([a, b], '1');
console.log(result); // [{id: '2'}]
```

If it's not what you're looking for, please describe your data structures with an example.

#### Update

Thanks for the data structures examples. I'm curious why do you need to have generics for your `deleteNestedArrayItem` function?

```
function deleteNestedArrayItem(categoryList: Category[], categoryId: number,  skillId: number) {
  // 1. find a category by categoryId
  // 2. find a skill in category by skillId
  // 3. delete the item
}
```

This function signature seems to cover your needs.

Comment: Agreed, id part was just misleading extra info. Question is only about how to declare the interface that type T will  contain Type U, which will be an array.

Comment: Like in objects we have  <T, K extends keyof T>

Comment: Type declarations are built on top of data structures you want to work with. Please provide an example of your actual data. Like `let array = [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}]`. Or `let array = [[{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}], [{id: '3'}, {id: '4'}]]`.

Comment: And id were used because array indices may get messed up in distributed data due to concurrent modifications. Similar approach is taken in firebase.